# Finite dimensional representation of tensor product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$ algebras, and let $\pi:A \odot B \to B(H)$ be a $*$-representation of the algebraic tensor product on a finite dimensional Hilbert space $H$. Let $x \in A \odot B$. Since $H$ is finite dimensional, by general theory $\pi$ factors through the minimal tensor product $A \otimes_{\mathrm{min}} B$ and hence for every $\epsilon > 0$ there are Hilbert spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ and $*$-representations $\alpha: A \to B(H_1)$ and $\beta: B \to B(H_2)$ such that $||(\alpha \otimes \beta)x|| \geq ||\pi(x)|| - \epsilon$. I would like to know how to explicitly construct such $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given $\pi$.

Comment: I guess one could try the following. Since $\pi(A)$ and $\pi(B)$ are finite dimensional von Neumann algebras, there are minimal projections $\{P_1,…,P_n\}$ in $\pi(A)$ and $\{Q_1,…,Q_m\}$ in $\pi(B)$ which sum to $I$. Then consider $\pi(A)$ acting on the span of $P_i \pi(A)P_j$ for $i,j \in  \{1,…,n\}$ and $\pi(B)$ acting on $Q_i\pi(B)Q_j$. Is this isomorphic to a tensor product representation?

Comment: Since $\pi(A\odot B)$ is a quotient of the C*-algebra $\pi(A)\otimes_{min}\pi(B)$ can't you just let $\alpha=\pi|_A$ and $\beta=\pi|_B$?   In general you won't be able to get anything tighter than this, for example if $A=B$ is a finite dimensional commutative C*-algebra, then this is the only thing that will work for the representation $x\otimes y\mapsto xy$

Comment: We need the space underlying the representation $\alpha \otimes \beta$ to be a tensor product of Hilbert spaces. Is your suggestion to take $H_1 = H_2 = H$ so that $\alpha \otimes \beta$ is a representation on $H \otimes H$?

Comment: Yes, that's my suggestion